# r shiny open folder on client side

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I created a actionbutton to open a network folder.

But when the client clicks on the actionbutton, the folder opens in the Server side and not in the Client Side. I am using this function to open the folder:

```
opendir <- function(dir) {
    if (.Platform['OS.type'] == "windows"){
      shell.exec(dir)
    } else {
      system(paste(Sys.getenv("R_BROWSER"), dir))
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try shinyFiles - https://github.com/thomasp85/shinyFiles ?

Comment: I read shinyFiles pdf and didnt find any function that corresponds to what I want. Do you have any suggestion?